# Is it possible to change Gmail signature for mobile client using Gmail API?

Tags: android, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I am able to change the signature for Gmail website using [sendAs->patch request](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/alias_and_signature_settings#python)  - it works perfectly fine, although the signature is not attached when sending emails from the Android client.

I noticed there is a different "Mobile device signature" option in my Android Gmail app, but I couldn't find a way to update it using the API.

Is there a way to either include the "main" signature in the Android app or change the mobile signature through the API?"

Comment: Can you try [this one](https://support.google.com/mail/thread/10913231?hl=en&msgid=67690786)?